# Simplifying subtraction of Sqrt terms

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify the following expression with terms inside the `Sqrt` function that can be simplified:

$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{(c-1) c}}-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{(c-1) c}}$$

**Code:**

```
Simplify[-(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[(-1 + c) c]) + Sqrt[a/((-1 + c) c)]]
```

[image]

which basically returns the input, though the answer should be zero. How can I ensure that the output is zero?

Comment: Not necessarily true for complex inputs: e.g. `FindInstance[-Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[(-1 + c) c]+Sqrt[a/((-1 + c) c)] != 0, {a, b, c}]` returns a perfectly valid solution for $a, b, c$ for which the formula given does not equal 0. You can simplify assuming the reals however if you know that this isn't a potential issue: `Simplify[..., Reals]`

Answer (score 7):

$\sqrt\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ only under these conditions

```
Reduce[Sqrt[a/c] == Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[c], {a, c}, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can find the conditions for your case the same way

```
Reduce[Sqrt[a/((-1 + c) c)] == Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[(-1 + c) c], {a, c}, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can do

```
ClearAll[a, c]
Assuming[a >= 0 && (c < 0 || c > 1), 
 Simplify[-(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[(-1 + c) c]) + Sqrt[a/((-1 + c) c)]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = -(Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[(-1 + c) c]) + Sqrt[a/((-1 + c) c)];
```

---

**Using `PowerExpand`:**

The "universally correct" answer according to the docs will be:

```
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> True]
```

$$\frac{\sqrt{a} \exp \left(i \pi  \left\lfloor -\frac{\arg (a)}{2 \pi }+\frac{\arg (c-1)}{2 \pi }+\frac{\arg (c)}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor \right)}{\sqrt{c-1} \sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{a} \exp \left(i \pi  \left(\left\lfloor -\frac{\arg (c-1)}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arg (c)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor +1\right)\right)}{\sqrt{c-1} \sqrt{c}}$$

---

The expression has two parts and with default assumptions:

```
{PowerExpand[expr[[1]]], PowerExpand[expr[[2]]]}
```

$$\left\{\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c-1} \sqrt{c}},-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c-1} \sqrt{c}}\right\}$$

```
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> Automatic]
```

> 0